# Chef Client Server Authentication through Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra

I'm trying to provision a Vagrant instance with Chef by connecting to a Chef server.

My `Vagrantfile` looks similar to this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "opentable/win-2012r2-standard-amd64-nocm"
    config.vm.provider = "virtualbox"
    config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
    config.vm.guest = :windows

    config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
    config.berkshelf.enabled = true

    config.vm.provision :chef_client do |chef|
      chef.chef_server_url = "https://chef.website.com"
      chef.validation_key_path = "C:/chef/validation.pem"
      chef.run_list = ["recipe[cookbook::default]"]
    end
end
```

According to [this documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_client.html), this `Vagrantfile` should contain all the fields I need to connect to the Chef server and pull down the relevant cookbooks and databags.

However, I am running into the following error when running the Chef client provisioner:

```
The following berks command failed to execute:

    C:\opscode\chefdk\embedded\bin/berks.BAT upload --berksfile C:/path/to/cookbook/Berksfile --no-freeze --force

The stdout and stderr are shown below:

    stdout: E, [2015-08-10T17:02:57.654352 #8488] ERROR -- : Ridley::Errors::ClientKeyNotFoundOrInvalid: client key is not found or invalid or not found at: 'C:/chef/client.pem'
```

Indeed, the `client.pem` is not there.

While the error itself is pretty self explanatory, I don't understand why I need to specify a `client.pem` on the initial Chef client run.

Is there a way for Vagrant to create this itself? Better yet, can I make it so that it doesn't need a client identifier at all?

This is only a Vagrant instance, so I don't need to keep this node on the Chef server. Based on [the Chef client provisioner documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_client.html) I don't see why I need a `client.pem` file, as the intructions make no mention of this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling Berkshelf

```
config.berkshelf.enabled = false
```

Bootstrapping a new Chef client against a chef server does not require Berkshelf. Berkshelf is a tool used on Chef *workstations* to manage cookbooks on the chef server.

PS

The Vagrant-berkshelf plugin at one stage was [deprecated](https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/) in favour of [Test kitchen](http://kitchen.ci/). It appears to be back again, but in the meantime I've grown to appreciate the benefits of Test Driven Infrastructure!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, it's a very good point. I'm not sure why having Berks on would cause it to nag about a `client.pem` file, but it's worth a shot. I'll try it out. Thanks! And I definitely agree that TDD is so important!

Comment: @JamesTaylor Berkshelf is a separate tool, similar to knife. Both are designed to be run on a chef workstation, not a chef node/client. That is why it assumes there is a client cert file.

Comment: O'Conner Unfortunately this did not fix the problem. Chef still complained about needing a `client.pem` file. I ended up just using the `chef_solo` provisioner and storing the databags locally on the machine. Thanks for your help, though!